# What does the Eval scales means in TensorFlow DeepLab Model Zoo?

Tags: tensorflow, deeplab

I'm trying to train a model using the models here
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/model_zoo.md
What does the Eval scales here means? I thought it may be scale for the image size but why it is three dimension in some cases?
Thank you!

Comment: Questions about the use of third-party software are not on-topic on Stack Overflow. It might be worth taking the site's [tour] and checking [what topics can be asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to improve the reception of future questions.

Answer (score 3):

*eval_scales* is a **list** of scales which are used to resize the image in the evaluation process. The default value is [1.0] --> The image is not resized and no multi-scale test is performed. If you provide a list with multiple scale values (for instance: [0.5, 1.0]) the network is evaluated by performing multiple inferences using varying image resolutions.

By using *eval_scales*, you can't specify the scaling of a certain image dimension but each scaling factor is applied on both spatial dimensions of the input image.